# What can I do about minimizing small shards of ice shooting out the ice dispenser on LG refrigerator?

Tags: refrigerator

Ever since we bought this fridge it's been doing this with the ice dispenser.  It's only 3-4 months old and I've tried cleaning out the tray where the ice is made but to no avail.

Comment: What ice feeding mechanism does this refirgerator use? Many modern refrigerators use a stainless steel screw-type mechanism to feed ice from the ice tray out through the ice dispenser. Ice chips are just a fact of life due to the screw mechanism occaissionally breaking some of the cubes.

Comment: Have you contacted the manufacturer?

Comment: Are you getting someone's left over crushed ice or do you get malformed, sometimes hollow cubes?

Comment: Really the best way to describe it is tiny pieces of ice that shoot all over the place, in addition to the regularly shaped cubes we'd expect to see when dispensing.

Comment: I recently purchased a brand new LG fridge, and the small trapdoor that the ice comes out of did not open until excessive ice weight sat on it.  This caused small bits of ice to flake out and water to melt down. I was told by the LG-sourced repairman (under warranty!) that this was due to some of the fridges being shipped with bad motors for the trapdoor.  He replaced the motor, and now the trapdoor opens perfectly and we get ice just fine.  Check whether or not your trapdoor opens properly.

Comment: This is one reason i'd be interested in a fridge that did chilled water but _not_ automatic ice.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like its the quality of the produced ice which is easy to break up, try cleaning the ice tray with vinegar then soapy water,  that may reduce the mineral deposits on the tray and reduce surface resistance.

I don't have a direct answer, only suggestions, since this is quite a complicated question.

Firstly, if you look at the new ice, fresh from the ice maker, are they solid?, then take one out and see if the ice block is very cloudy, this would make the ice slightly more fragile, since it contains many air bubbles.  you could try turning the freezer to a slightly higher temperature to get the ice to freeze slower.

If the ice is falling out of the tray already flaky, then the problem is in the tray

I would suggest taking all existing ice out if the unit. cleaning everything then checking if there is a change.

as a second experiment, you could wait for an empty tray, then manually pour distilled water into the ice tray and see if you get better ice. in that case your water has too many minerals etc.

Comment: I have never heard of mineralized water making fragile cubes, but not saying it isn't true.  Indeed, my experience may be consistent with that.  We have an LG frig with the ice maker in the door, very hard water (450+ TDS), and get the occasional chips in addition to cubes.  IMO, there is nothing to be done.  As the posted answer suggests, I think it is the dispenser paddles (for lack of a better word) that break up cubes from time to time.  I think it is worse when some of the cubes are sticking together from not drawing ice frequently enough or some other cause I don't know about.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure the ice reservoir is free of accumulated frost as this can tend to slough off amid ice dispensing